# Integrate igraph's community detection with neo4j

Tags: r, graph, nosql, neo4j, igraph

I am using the label.propagation.community algorithm from igraph package in R, to cluster my network.
if my graph data base is in neo4j database format, is there any R library that will let me load the data from the database into R?
Any example that shows how we can connect from R to neo4j will be also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a specific R package to connect to neo4j.

But , using `RCurl` and `RJSONIO` you can load your graph from neo4J.

1. CurlPerform to execute the query
2. fromJSON to transform the result to a data.frame

Comment: Would love to see a tutorial or blog/screencast on this!

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot, you should post that to the mailing list, https://groups.google.com/group/neo4j/about

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, Neo4j now has direct R support: [RNeo4j](http://neo4j.com/developer/r/)